# What's the fastest way of finding the longest chain of strings with common first/last characters?

Tags: python

This one seems pretty straightforward but I'm having trouble implementing it in Python.

Say you have an array of strings, all of length 2: `["ab","bc","cd","za","ef","fg"]`

There are two chains here: `"zabcd"` and `"efg"`

What's the most efficient way of finding the longest one? (in this case it would be `"zabcd"`).
Chains can be cyclical too... for instance `["ab","bc","ca"]` (in this particular case the length of the chain would be 3).

Comment: This looks like homework, so please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: this isn't homework @ThierryLathuille. I've already solved this by creating a power set of each possible combination and then dropping the ones without consecutive letters. However this is pretty computationally intensive and I'm trying to figure out if there's a better way of doing it. BTW I am not even a student, just brushing up on some Python for my next job as I haven't used it in a while and this is one of the problems I found in a book that I'm using to practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly a graph problem, with the characters being the vertices and the pairs being unweighted directed edges.

Without allowing cycles in the solution, this is the [longest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem), and it is NP-hard, so "efficient" is probably out of the window, even if cycles are allowed (to get rid of the solution cycles, split the vertices in two, one for incoming edges and one for out-going edges, with an edge in-between). According to Wikipedia, no **good** approximation scheme is known.

If the graph is acyclic, then you can do it in linear time, as the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) mentions:

> A longest path between two given vertices s and t in a weighted graph
> G is the same thing as a shortest path in a graph −G derived from G by
> changing every weight to its negation. Therefore, if shortest paths
> can be found in −G, then longest paths can also be found in G.[4]
>
> For most graphs, this transformation is not useful because it creates
> cycles of negative length in −G. But if G is a directed acyclic graph,
> then no negative cycles can be created, and a longest path in G can be
> found in linear time by applying a linear time algorithm for shortest
> paths in −G, which is also a directed acyclic graph.[4] For instance,
> for each vertex v in a given DAG, the length of the longest path
> ending at v may be obtained by the following steps:
>
> Find a topological ordering of the given DAG. For each vertex v of the
> DAG, in the topological ordering, compute the length of the longest
> path ending at v by looking at its incoming neighbors and adding one
> to the maximum length recorded for those neighbors. If v has no
> incoming neighbors, set the length of the longest path ending at v to
> zero. In either case, record this number so that later steps of the
> algorithm can access it. Once this has been done, the longest path in
> the whole DAG may be obtained by starting at the vertex v with the
> largest recorded value, then repeatedly stepping backwards to its
> incoming neighbor with the largest recorded value, and reversing the
> sequence of vertices found in this way.

There are other special cases where there are efficient algorithms available, notably trees, but since you allow cycles that probably doesn't apply to you.

I didn't give an algorithm here for you, but that should give you the right direction for your research. The problem itself may be straightforward, but an **efficient** solution is **NOT**.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was wondering. Much appreciated... I was going crazy thinking there might be a quicker way of doing it.